# Run Perl script in Linux environment

Tags: linux, perl

I'm trying to run code on Linux environment

Here's the code (saved as hello.pl):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Hello You\n";
```

Here's what I tried on my linux environment:

```
%perl hello.pl
```

I tried listing out the path starting from `C:\Users\...` and so on

I keep getting error that says:

```
Can't open perl script "hello.pl": No such file or directory
```

Comment: Have you set the file permissions (e.g. chmod 774 hello.pl)?

Comment: Where did you save it?

Comment: When I try chmod 774 it said this: chmod: cannot access âhello.plâ: No such file or directory

Comment: I saved it in my Documents under a folder

Comment: Can you paste the results of "ls -al" from the directory containing hello.pl?

Comment: You said you have a linux environment, then you said the path starts with C:\. That does not make any sense. That's a Windows path.

Comment: @ikegami my assumption is cygwin is the linux environment

Comment: Cygwin paths don't start with C: either

Comment: im accessing a linux machine through SSH. I dont know if that helps or not?

Comment: To run `perl hello.pl`, the current directory for the terminal must be the directory where `hello.pl` is stored.  You said you saved it in Documents; then if your current directory is not the Documents directory, you need to run `perl ~/Documents/hello.pl` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You have to be located in the same folder with the `hello.pl` in the "window" (aka terminal, or console) that you try to execute `perl hello.pl`.

On linux, you can determine the folder that you're in by issuing `pwd`.

If you're not in the same folder (the most probable cause of your error), you have 2 options:

1. Navigate to that folder with `cd /path/to/your/script/location` you have to replace the `/path/to/your/script/location` in the example, with your actual path
2. Execute the file with `perl /path/to/hello.pl` - of course, you have to replace the `/path/to/` in the example, with your ac

Also, you can try and view the file from the console running a `less hello.pl`

Answer (score 1):

In cygwin you might try: `/cygdrive/c/Users/bonan/Desktop/perl/hello.pl`.

Alternatively at your prompt try tying in just `perl` without hitting enter, and then drag the hello.pl file from its file explorer location into the terminal window. That should paste the full file path to the file as text into the command prompt. If you're using `cygwin` I forget it if properly pastes the path with forward-slashes, like `/cygdrive/c/Users/bonan/Desktop/perl/hello.pl`, or if it pastes what it would in `cmd` with backslashes as you've indicated you typed yourself.

The other thing to do that's relatively easy is right click the file and choose to open a terminal or shell here, which for `cygwin` you can get in your context menu by running `chere -i` once (it actually says "Bash prompt here" I think). And there's similar context menu options for cmd, powershell, an actual linux bash, or mac os x's terminal ... once you're in the same path as the file, you can just type `perl hel`<kbd>tab</kbd> and autocomplete the filename assuming no other files in the same folder start with "hel".